# Android: Using frameworks vs bare metal programming?

Tags: android

I've just finished designing my fairly simple yet complete game for Android, with menus, multiple views etc. Now I'd like to move on to something more complicated, maybe with OpenGL.

I see people on gamedev.stackexchange using all sorts of game frameworks. What's the advantage of doing that as opposed to doing everything manually in Java, animating sprites myself etc? Does using these frameworks not make my code less portable across iOS and Android?

And should I really be coding in C++/JNI if portability will be a future goal?
Sorry if the question appears obvious, but I'd like to get confirmation from people more experienced than me.

Thanks

Comment: It depends how you define portability. If you write your own "engine" using Java, it shouldn't be a problem to rewrite it using Object-C or C later on. But if it's cross platform compiling you're after, I'm afraid NDK/JNI is the only way. As for frameworks I can't tell much but if they provide support for Android and iOS I see no reason they didn't provide good portability support too.

Comment: Frameworks provide a way to have reusable code. So if you were to reinvent everything yourself, in your own classes and methods, and made it so that it's reusable, that would be a framework.

Well... iOS supports C++ also, so that may be a boon. But... you still have to port the code.